# How to return JSON Object from mysql?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to set this object:

```
var userPref = {}
```

to the mysql return from this query:

```
var qSelect = "SELECT age_min, age_max, max_distance, partner_gender_id, partner_children, partner_family_plans FROM User_Preferences WHERE user_id = ?";
            var qValues = [user_pref_id];
            var qCall = mysql.format(qSelect, qValues);
            connection.query(qCall, function(err, userPrefFound, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("get my preferences error: " + err);
                    callback(false);
                } else {
                    userPref = userPrefFound[0];
                    console.log("userPref", userPref)
                    if (userPrefFound.length > 0 && userPref.max_distance < 300) {
                        getUserLocation();
                    } else {
                        getUserPrefEth();

                    }
                }
            });
```

My userPref prints out as a RowDataPacket

```
userPref RowDataPacket {
  age_min: 18,
  age_max: 65,
  max_distance: 5,
  partner_gender_id: 2,
  partner_children: 2,
  partner_family_plans: 3 }
```

which then does not allow me to set the object like so

```
var politics_interested = [];
        var qSelect = "SELECT politics_type FROM User_Pref_Politics WHERE user_id = ?";
        var qValues = [user_pref_id];
        var qCall = mysql.format(qSelect, qValues);
        connection.query(qCall, function(err, userPrefPolitics, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("get my preferences politics error: " + err);
                callback(false);
            } else {
                if (userPrefPolitics.length > 0) {
                    userPrefPolitics.forEach(function(i) {

                        politics_interested.push(i.politics_type);
                    });
                }
                console.log("politics_interested", userPref)
                userPref["politics_interested"] = politics_interested;
                getUserPrefMarital();

            }
        });
```

and prints this error:

```
\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:437
      throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'politics_interested' of undefined
```

How do I go about taking the return value from mysql and setting it as an object?

I tried this for an array userPref['religious_level_interested'] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userPrefRelig)); but when I try it for an object it does not work, not sure if that works either.

Comment: Is the second `connection.query` call a within the `getUserPrefEth()` function?

Comment: They are in separate functions but userPref = {} is outside of them

Comment: Ah is it possible there is a race condition hm

Comment: Yes. I believe you're trying to set politics_interested before the first query completes.